# cakephp session data and forms

Tags: database, forms, cakephp

Hi all I'm trying to create a form where a user can create a new user which will have the  same account_id as the person creating the user.

currently my page is displaying the correct account_id in the form but when we submit the form to the database it saves as the wrong thing.

here is my function

```
      function add_Employee(){

        $accounts=$this->User->find('list', array(
        'fields'=>array('account_id'),
        'conditions' => array(
        'User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));

    if($this->request->is('post')){
    $this->User->create(); 
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) 
    { 
        $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved');  
        $this->redirect( array('controller'=>'Users','action' => 'index_admin')); 
    }
    else { $this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'); } 
    }
    $this->set('accounts',$accounts);


  }
```

and the view

```
  <h2>Add Employee</h2>
<p>Add a new Employee here, please enter their details below.</p>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action'=>'add_Employee'));
echo $this->Form->input('username',array('label'=>'Username: '));
echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label'=>'Password: '), array('type'=>'password'));
echo $this->Form->input('password_confirmation',array('label'=>'Confirm: '), array('type'=>'password'));
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('label'=>'Email: '));
echo $this->Form->input('title',array('label'=>'Title: '));
echo $this->Form->input('firstname',array('label'=>'First Name: '));
echo $this->Form->input('surname',array('label'=>'Surname: '));
echo $this->Form->input('active', array('default'=>true, 'type'=>'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('account_id', array('value'=>$accounts['User']['account_id']));
echo $this->Form->input('access_level', array(
    'label' => 'Access Level:', 
    'options' => array('1'=>'Employee','2'=>'Adminstrator')));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

Comment: What it prints with `pr($account['User']);`?

Comment: thats just pr($accounts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put account id as value in form :

```
In controller:

 $accounts=$this->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
    'id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));
 $this->set('account',$accounts);

In view :
echo $this->Form->input('account_id', array('label'=>'Account','value'=>$account['User']['account_id']));
```

Comment: still adding to the database as 1, the value should be 2. user.id=1 but user.account_id=2

Comment: has an undefined index on $account[user]

Comment: Array
(
    [2] => 3
)
Account .... 2=user.id, 3 is the account.id im trying to get

Comment: I think you still trying with 'list' in controller, and I have posted 'first' for that  $accounts=$this->User->find('first',......

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15548/discussion-between-krishna-and-user1393064)

Comment: echo $this->Form->input('account_id', array('value'=>$accounts['User']['account_id'],'type'=>'text'));